# how to get the texbox value from view to viewmodel in silverlight mvvm?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, prism

In my project i'm using Silverlight5 with MVVM Pattern.
I have the following:

```
View        : Manager.xaml
Code-Behind : Manager.Xaml.cs
ViewModel   : ManagerViewModel.cs
```

in my view i have one textbox and i have assigned the value is 10.

Manager.xaml

```
<TextBox Name="gid" Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

Manager.xaml.cs

```
gid.Text=(((TextBlock)DG.Columns[5].GetCellContent(DG.SelectedItem)).Text);
ManageViewModel vm = DataContext as ManageViewModel;
            if (vm != null)
            {
                vm.EditCommand.Execute();
            }
```

ManagerViewModel.cs:

```
private DelegateCommand _editCommand;
    public DelegateCommand EditCommand
    {
        get
        {

            if (_editCommand == null)
                _editCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
                {
                    **//Here i need to get the value that is assigned in the textbox.**
                    ANCViewModel.Show();
                });
            return _editCommand;
        }
    }
```

Here my question is how i have to get the value that is assigned in the textbox from view to ViewModel. Any Help..?

Comment: I Think You Should Use Two Way Binding Of Do This

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your code.

```
ManageViewModel vm = DataContext as ManageViewModel;
```

your DataContext is ManageViewModel so you should use this context...

```
< TextBox Name="gid" Text={Binding MyTextPropertyInMyViewModel} 
  Visibility="Collapsed" why ? />
```

Your delegate command is also in ViewModel so you can use MyTextPropertyInMyViewModel in your view model easily.

If you use MVVM ,it means you use a DataContext (or it can be a resource) .You should use it for UI elements source's and also for Commanding.

By this way you separate Business and UI. 
ViewModel's are our business objects,and you may think Model's are our entities.

So you should use bindings over your DataContext for your DataGrid's,TextBlock's and other visual elements and manage your bussiness on your viewModel. By this way you may use your view model somewhere else. i.e. In your mobile app.